# Slow in zoom, pan

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, performance

I am working on GIS tool but it is very slow when try to zoom, pan or open attributes. can any one suggest is there any way to make it fast?

Comment: What GIS tool are you using? What data do you have open? This can very often be an issue due to heavy data. Try with some other smaller data and see if the problem continues.

Comment: If you are using shapefiles, make sure they have valid spatial indexes. If not, redraw becomes *significantly* slower.

Answer (score 2):

You might try disabling [Hardware Acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_acceleration).
If not supported, having that enabled could be taxing on your machine.
You can disable it by:
Customize --> ArcMap Options --> Data View --> Hardware Acceleration

[image]